# npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer error next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @react-oauth/google@0.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-oauth/google
npm ERR!     @react-oauth/google@"^0.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.1.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"12.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (react-dom, react-icons, styled-jsx, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!     react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Mr. Aka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mr. Aka\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-10T19_35_56_488Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 1):

Try using `npm cache verify` and after `npm cache clean --force`. It may then ask you to run another command to permanently solve the issue which is caused by older versions of npm, run that command and it should be solved (worked for me).